# bind dataframes with names of dataframes as an additional id column

Tags: r

I have 3 data frames in R 
lets say:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 1:6, y = 1:6)
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = 1:4)
```

and I would like to merge them together to create a new data frame that would have as first column the name of the data frame for each row of that data frame.
I would look like this:

```
   df x y
1  df1 1 1
2  df1 2 2
3  df1 3 3
4  df1 4 4
5  df1 5 5
6  df2 1 1
7  df2 2 2
8  df2 3 3
9  df2 4 4
10 df2 5 5
11 df2 6 6
12 df3 1 1
13 df3 2 2
14 df3 3 3
15 df3 4 4
```

Any ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package. This will work with arbitrary numbers of data frames. The `ls` call gets all the variables in the namespace that begin with 'df'; `mget` gives you a named list of the data frames. The `.id` argument lets you specify column name.

```
df_out <- bind_rows(mget(ls(pattern='df')), .id='df')
```

Output is as follows:

```
    df x y
1  df1 1 1
2  df1 2 2
3  df1 3 3
4  df1 4 4
5  df1 5 5
6  df2 1 1
7  df2 2 2
8  df2 3 3
9  df2 4 4
10 df2 5 5
11 df2 6 6
12 df3 1 1
13 df3 2 2
14 df3 3 3
15 df3 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and very basic approach:

```
rbind(df1=df1,df2=df2,df3=df3)
```

The result:

```
      x y
df1.1 1 1
df1.2 2 2
df1.3 3 3
df1.4 4 4
df1.5 5 5
df2.1 1 1
df2.2 2 2
df2.3 3 3
df2.4 4 4
df2.5 5 5
df2.6 6 6
df3.1 1 1
df3.2 2 2
df3.3 3 3
df3.4 4 4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm pretty new to R but isn't there a way to not have the .1, .2 etc.. after the df name and binding them one by one using a loop?

Comment: those are also rownames, not a column name

Answer (score 1):

Sticking with base R functions and expanding on NelsonGon's answer a little:

```
d <- rbind(df1=df1, df2=df2, df3=df3)
d <- cbind(df=sub("..$", "", rownames(d)), data.frame(d, row.names=NULL))
d
    df x y
1  df1 1 1
2  df1 2 2
3  df1 3 3
4  df1 4 4
5  df1 5 5
6  df2 1 1
7  df2 2 2
8  df2 3 3
9  df2 4 4
10 df2 5 5
11 df2 6 6
12 df3 1 1
13 df3 2 2
14 df3 3 3
15 df3 4 4
```

This uses cbind to add modified rownames as a column.